# jQuery clone() is not working as expected

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have following html select element :

```
<div class="addmore_box_date">
    <div class="row">

        <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-4">            
               <input type='text' name="add_date[]" class="form-control" id="add_date" placeholder="Select date">
          </div>

          <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-4">
            <select class="form-control add_time" id="add_time" name="add_time[]">
                <option value="">Select time</option>
                <option value="12:00 Am">12:00 Am</option>
                <option value="1:00 Am">1:00 Am</option>
                <option value="2:00 Am">2:00 Am</option>
                <option value="3:00 Am">3:00 Am</option>
                <option value="4:00 Am">4:00 Am</option>
                <option value="5:00 Am">5:00 Am</option>
                <option value="6:00 Am">6:00 Am</option>
                <option value="7:00 Am">7:00 Am</option>
                <option value="8:00 Am">8:00 Am</option>
                <option value="9:00 Am">9:00 Am</option>
                <option value="10:00 Am">10:00 Am</option>
                <option value="11:00 Am">11:00 Am</option>
                <option value="12:00 Pm">12:00 Pm</option>
                <option value="1:00 Pm">1:00 Pm</option>
                <option value="2:00 Pm">2:00 Pm</option>
                <option value="3:00 Pm">3:00 Pm</option>
                <option value="4:00 Pm">4:00 Pm</option>
                <option value="5:00 Pm">5:00 Pm</option>
                <option value="6:00 Pm">6:00 Pm</option>
                <option value="7:00 Pm">7:00 Pm</option>
                <option value="8:00 Pm">8:00 Pm</option>
                <option value="9:00 Pm">9:00 Pm</option>
                <option value="10:00 Pm">10:00 Pm</option>
                <option value="11:00 Pm">11:00 Pm</option>
            </select>                                  
        </div>                      
    </div>                                      
    <br/>
</div>                                      
<label for=""><a id="addmoredate">Add more date & time</a></label>
```

There are link to add more date and time using this id `addmoredate`

So, for this I am using following JQuery code but first time it's adding one select element. It's okey but second time when I add more then it's adding 3 select elements but it's should be add 1 by 1.

```
var max_fields      = 30; //maximum input boxes allowed
var wrapper         = $(".addmore_box_date"); //Fields wrapper
var add_button      = $("#addmoredate"); //Add button ID

$('#add_date').datetimepicker({     
    timepicker:false,
    format:'Y-m-d',
    formatDate:'Y/m/d',
    minDate:'-1970/01/02', // yesterday is minimum date
    maxDate:'+2017/12/01', // and tommorow is maximum date calendar     

});    

var x = 1; //initlal text box count    
$(add_button).click(function(e){ //on add input button click
   e.preventDefault();

   if(x < max_fields){ //max input box allowed           
       x++; //text box increment


       $(wrapper).append("<span id='date_time_close'><div class='row'><div class='col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-4'><input type='text' name='add_date[]' class='form-control' id='add_date"+x+"' placeholder='Select date'></div><div class='col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-4'><div class='new_select'></div></div><a class='remove_date_time pull-right'>&nbsp;Close</a></div></span>");   

       if(x == 2) {
        var y = x+1;
        $('select.add_time').clone().attr('class', 'add_time'+y).appendTo('.new_select');
       } else {             
        alert(x);
        $('select.add_time'+x).clone().attr('class', 'add_time'+x).appendTo('.new_select');
       }


     $('#add_date'+x).datetimepicker({      
        timepicker:false,
        format:'Y-m-d',
        formatDate:'Y/m/d',
        minDate:'-1970/01/02', // yesterday is minimum date
        maxDate:'+2017/12/01', // and tommorow is maximum date calendar                 
    });     

   }
});
```

**First time it's showing like that :**

[image]

**But second time it's adding more more select element instead of 1**

[image]

Comment: On every click you are appending new element with same ID `date_time_close` - Wrong!

Comment: I think problem is not about `date_time_close` id. You see that text `Add more data & time`. when I click on this text link it's showing 1 select element and then showing more select elements..

Comment: @Justinas did not say that it is because of wrong id, he is suggesting you that it is not good to have same ids. Not a good practice.

Answer (score 2):

Because everytime you are appending to this element based on the class which got cloned on every row and so it find this on other rows as well and adds them there also

```
.appendTo('.new_select');
```

Try this

```
$(add_button).click(function(e){ //on add input button click
   e.preventDefault();

   if(x < max_fields){ //max input box allowed           
       x++; //text box increment

       var newRow = $("<span id='date_time_close'><div class='row'><div class='col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-4'><input type='text' name='add_date[]' class='form-control' id='add_date"+x+"' placeholder='Select date'></div><div class='col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-4'><div class='new_select'></div></div><a class='remove_date_time pull-right'>&nbsp;Close</a></div></span>");

       /* if(x == 2) {
          var y = x+1;
          newRow.find('.new_select').append($('select.add_time').clone().attr('class', 'add_time'+y));
       } else {             
           //alert(x);
           newRow.find('.new_select').append($('select.add_time'+x).clone().attr('class', 'add_time'+x));

       }*/

      newRow.find('.new_select').append($('select.add_time').clone().attr('class', 'add_time'+x));
      $(wrapper).append(newRow);  

   }
});
```

**[Example Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/m41d2woj/)**

Comment: I see. but I changed the class name. Can you please show me the working example ?

Comment: let me try with this.

Comment: Not working. 3rd time it's don't showing the select element.

Comment: Check now it is working. I have commented few lines because I did not get why do you need them. Let me know if you have some purpose of those commented lines then we can think of something else

Comment: Yes, It's working perfectly. Thanks a lot Pawan Nogariya ;)

Comment: Glad it helped you! :)

Comment: Hi I have an issue... When I close the any new date and time box and then again add to a new one then the date is not working. I think it's can't find correct class

Comment: So that's why you uncheck my answer as not correct? Even though it fixed the problem that you mentioned in the question, now this is something new and a new problem

Comment: You didn't even post the close button code in your question at all and now you are asking why it is not working after close button click?

Comment: You used my code and asked another question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37428888/jquery-clone-issue. Great!

Comment: We both know what we are doing. Do you agree to stop it and undo what was already done from both sides, you and me?

Comment: The system automatically reversed what we did, so now I think we can go on our own ways.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
$(document).on("click", "#addmoredate", function(){
   add_more($(".row:last"));
});
function add_more(evt)
{
    var curr = evt;
    var item = $(curr).clone(true);
    $(curr).parent().append("<br/>").append(item).show();
}
</script>
```